# How to add ~/.zshrc file into git?

Tags: git, backup

I would like to create a backup of the `.zshrc` file in my `~/` directory and avoid versioning all other items. How to exclude all subdirectories and their content?

For example:

```
cd ~/subdirectory/ && git status
```

should output:

```
fatal: Not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /)
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: I would rather create a new git repository in a directory inside `~` and make `~/.zshrc` a symlink to `.zshrc` in the repository.  This is a common way for managing dotfiles.

Comment: Use <https://github.com/RichiH/vcsh>, but the question is unfit for SO, it's for https://superuser.com or https://unix.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

To exclude all excepted zhrc file (put in your .gitignore file):

```
/*
!.zhrc
```

Comment: unfortunately, this does not work. When I execute:

`cd ~/subdirectory/ && git status`

I get:

`nothing added to commit but untracked files present`.

The expected output was:

`fatal: Not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /)`

Comment: True. You will not version files/folders excepted the zhrc one (which is under the hood the expected behaviour), but infortunately there is no way to prevent the described behaviour (as far as i know), since the git command will search the nearest .git folder in the folder path and display "fatal: Not a git repository" if fails